# Deserialize a property as an ExpandoObject using JSON.NET

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net, .net-4.5, expandoobject

For example, there's an object like the next one:

```
public class Container
{
   public object Data { get; set; }
}
```

And it's used this way:

```
Container container = new Container
{
    Data = new Dictionary<string, object> { { "Text", "Hello world" } }
};
```

If I deserialize a JSON string obtained from serializing the above instance, the `Data` property, even if I provide the `ExpandoObjectConverter`, it's not deserialized as an `ExpandoObject`:

```
Container container = JsonConvert.Deserialize<Container>(jsonText, new ExpandoObjectConverter());
```

**How can I deserialize a class property assigned with an anonymous object, or at least, not concrete type as an `ExpandoObject`?**

### EDIT:

*Someone answered that I could just use the dynamic object. This won't work for me. I know I could go this way, but this isn't the case because I need an ExpandoObject.
Thanks.*

### EDIT 2:

*Some other user answered I could deserialize a JSON string into an `ExpandoObject`. This isn't the goal of this question. I need to deserialize a concrete type having a dynamic property. In the JSON string this property could be an associative array.*

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Try this:

```
Container container = new Container
{
    Data = new Dictionary<string, object> { { "Text", "Hello world" } }
};

string jsonText = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(container);

var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(jsonText, new ExpandoObjectConverter());
```

I found that doing this got me an `ExpandoObject` from the call to `DeserializeObject`. I think the issue with the code you have provided is that while you are supplying an `ExpandoObjectConverter`, you are asking `Json.Net` to deserialize a `Container`, so I would imagine that the `ExpandoObjectConverter` is not being used.

**Edit:**

If I decorate the `Data` property with `[JsonConverter(typeof(ExpandoObjectConverter))]` and use the code:

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Container>(jsonText);
```

Then the `Data` property is deserialized to an `ExpandoObject`, while `obj` is a `Container`.

Comment: Thanks for the effort. But as the other answerer, I believe you didn't read the question carefully. I know that I can fully deserialize a JSON string into an `ExpandoObject`. It's harder than that: I need to deserialize a **concrete type** which has a dynamic property. I want the whole property as an `ExpandoObject` when deserialized.

Comment: Ah, so in your example the `Data` property would be deserialized as an `ExpandoObject`?

Comment: Sadly, the `Data` property isn't deserialized as an `ExpandoObject`, but a `JContainer` (a JSON.NET specific type). I need the whole `Data` as an `ExpandoObject`.

Comment: I don't know why I didn't receive any notification. I'm going to try this!

Comment: Great, great! It works. Thanks, it's going to be a good achievement in my developments.