# Using JSON.NET to deserialize into IEnumerable<KeyValuePair>

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm attempting to deserialize a list of key value pairs in JSON. I've seen other answers that suggest deserializing into a dictionary, but this won't work as I have duplicate keys. I could deserialize into a list of dictionaries, but this seems silly, because each one is only one key/value pair. This also complicates accessing those keys and values.

This is a property on a class and part of a larger JSON object, so any solution that requires deserializing this chunk of JSON separately isn't going to work for me.

I've seen [Deserialize array of key value pairs using Json.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15789539/deserialize-array-of-key-value-pairs-using-json-net). It's a possible solution, but while I'm not opposed to writing a custom deserializer if I have to, I would prefer to use something existing if possible.

Here's an example of my data:

`[{"Parcel": "Parcel_ID"}, {"Parcel": "LegalAddress"}, {"Fee": "Amount"}]`

Things I've tried:

`IEumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>>`  Doesn't work, both key and value are null.

`IEnumerable<Tuple<string, string>>` Doesn't work and is awkward.

`IEnumerable<IDictionary<string, string>>` Works, but is awkward to work with due to needing to do `FirstOrDefault().(Key|Value)`.

Comment: This looks a lot like http://stackoverflow.com/q/15789539/215552?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Yeah, if I do end up writing my own deserializer, that is what I would base it on. I was just hoping something had changed in the last 4 years.

Comment: How about adding `SelectMany` to your last try: `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Dictionary<string, string>>>(json).SelectMany(o => o)`?

Comment: Because it's a property on a class. This isn't the full JSON.

Comment: Doesn't you can't deserialise to an intermediate class and project it afterwards.

Comment: Sure, I could do that, but at that point I'm just going to write my own converter.

Comment: @MorganThrapp what result do you want to achieve? Maybe a sort of `List<Item>`, where `Item` is a class with 2 properties, `Key` and `Value`?

Comment: @MassimilianoKraus Yeah, that's what I'm doing for the moment. I was just trying to see if there was a builtin type that would work out of the box.

Comment: @MorganThrapp what about [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15455304/deserialize-a-property-as-an-expandoobject-using-json-net) ?

Answer (score -1):

If you have this kind of structure many times in your project, the best is to create your own converter with Newtonsoft as say in this [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21021655/json-serialize-listkeyvaluepairstring-object).